# subView of cell isn't fitting UITableView's Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to make it so when you tap on a UITableViewCell, a subview appears below it with a UIDatePicker. The frame isn't resizing however and I'm not sure how to do this. Here's a photo, you have to drag down to see the UIDatePicker (set in Time Mode).

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100);
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  // which should be 'now' right?
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;  // which creates just the clock
    [pickerView setDate:[NSDate date]];
    //[pickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    pickerView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [pickerView setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

    [cell addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.firstTable sizeToFit];
```

[image]

Comment: first of all, you should add subview to `contentView` of cell. So it should be:
`[cell.contentView addSubview:pickerView]`

Comment: Did that, the pickerview is still outside of the frame :C